# Is there any API to implement flow visualization like google flow visualization

Tags: javascript, d3.js, google-visualization, data-visualization, sankey-diagram

I am trying to implement flow visualization diagram like google flow visualization. Please suggest any API for this type of implementation. Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT** : I used **sankey diagrams** to achieve this requirement. Below is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var dataArray = [["India \n 40","United States \n 25","Canada \n 20","Hong Kong \n 15"],
                     ["page1 \n 50","page2 \n 30","about_us.htm \n 20"],
                     ["page2 \n 50","contactus.htm \n 15"],
                     ["page1 \n 50"]];

    var sankey = new Sankey();

    for(var i=0; i< dataArray.length; i++) 
    sankey.stack(i,dataArray[i]); 

    sankey.setData([["India \n 40",20,"page1 \n 50"],["United States \n 25",10,"page1 \n 50"],["Canada \n 20",10,"page1 \n 50"],["Hong Kong \n 15",10,"page1 \n 50"],["India \n 40",10,"page2 \n 30"],["United States \n 25",10,"page2 \n 30"],["Canada \n 20",5,"page2 \n 30"],["Hong Kong \n 15",5,"page2 \n 30"],["India \n 40",10,"about_us.htm \n 20"],["United States \n 25",5,"about_us.htm \n 20"],["Canada \n 20",5,"about_us.htm \n 20"],
                    ["page1 \n 50",35,"page2 \n 50"],["page2 \n 30",15,"page2 \n 50"],["page1 \n 50",10,"contactus.htm \n 15"],["page2 \n 30",5,"contactus.htm \n 15"],
                    ["page2 \n 50",40,"page1 \n 50"]
                    ]);

    sankey.setBubbles([["page1 \n 50", 5],["page2 \n 30",10],["about_us.htm \n 20",20],["contactus.htm \n 15",15],["page2 \n 50",10]]);

    sankey.bubbleColor = "#F37126";
    sankey.bubbleLabelColor = "#FFF";
    sankey.draw();
});
```

In the above example, I have "**page1 \n 50**" in **first** and **third** interaction. For this it will created only **one node in third interaction**. How to overcome this problem. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is a [Sankey diagram](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/).

Comment: I have tried sankey diagram also. I have faced one problem with these diagrams i.e if I have same node name in two levels it creates only single node. that's why I'm looking for another API

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you can't do that with sankey. You can add some other data such as stack number to the data so you can reduce duplication. This is how i am doing with it. It simply means none of my objects have same name in sankey chart.